# Netbeans 8.0.2 - missing "servers"

Tags: java, netbeans

I've just downloaded Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows.

Under the "Services" tab, I was expecting to get:

- Databases
- Web services
- Servers
- Hudson...
- Team...
- Issue...

Instead I've got the following:

- Databases
- Web services
- Maven Repositories
- Hudson Builders
- Task Repositories

Can anyone tell me why did I get this menu? What can I do to get the first menu? I'm completely new at this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you downloaded the **NetBeans Java SE Download Bundle**, this one doesn't contain the server adapters.

You need the **NetBeans Java EE Download Bundle** from https://netbeans.org/downloads/.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and rapid response. I did download the Netbeans All Download Bundle.

Comment: It's also found under the plugins as the EE bundle. You can easily find it when you search for "glassfish"